# Always get "The resulting API analysis file is too large."

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

When I submitting to iTunes Connect I always get this message:

> **iTunes Store operation succeeded with a warning.**
>
> The resulting API analysis file is too large. We were unable to
> validate your API usage prior to delivery. This is just an
> informational message.

[image]

And all builds stuck in "processing" state for a long time.
[image]

I'm using Objective-C and Swift code in my app.

***I know that on stackoverflow exist similar questions, but there no solution to fix it. Please don't mark my question as duplicate.***

Answer (score 3):

> It is just an **informational** message.

I submitted various apps with this message and they went without any problems into the store.

It can't do the `API` analysis before upload. It does this to check if you use any restricted `API's` from the `SDK`. *Because it's too large, you will get the informational message.*

Comment: I know but all builds stuck in "processing" state for a long time, it's annoying.

Comment: There is no way I currently know how to work around this, anyway I hope I could help you a bit. :)

Comment: I get this all the time. It does not prevent the app from being reviewed and approved but it makes the process seem sloppy.

Comment: Ah...
It's OK
It must to add build version

Comment: exist a way for remove this message?